# java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

> STAR=20110209
>   00:01:01|PNAM=test_.xml|PNUM=480|SSTA=20110209
>   00:01:01|STRT=20110209
>   00:01:01|STOP=20110209 00:01:01|

and i want to extract values of few of the keys here.

like whats the value of PNAM and SSTA.

I want a regular expression that can provide the values of few of the keys and keys can be in any order.

Comment: Can each key only appear once? can the values include the delimiter "|"

Comment: Can't you just split the string on `|` on  then split the parts on the `=`?

Comment: values don't have delimiter "|" and a key appears only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Java code:

```
String str = "STAR=20110209 00:01:01|PNAM=test_.xml|PNUM=480|SSTA=20110209 00:01:01|STRT=20110209 00:01:01|STOP=20110209 00:01:01|";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^=]*)=([^|]*)\\|");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
String pnamVal = null, sstaVal = null;
while (m.find()) {
    //System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(1) + '=' + m.group(2));
    if (m.group(1).equals("PNAM"))
        pnamVal = m.group(2);
    else if (m.group(1).equals("SSTA"))
        sstaVal = m.group(2);

    if (pnamVal != null && sstaVal != null)
       break;
}
System.out.println("SSTA: " + sstaVal);
System.out.println("PNAM: " + pnamVal);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
SSTA: 20110209 00:01:01
PNAM: test_.xml
```

Comment: i am going to using ur expression in this way ([PNAM|SSTA|STAR]*)=([^|]*)\\|

Comment: Sure you can make regex more restrictive like that. Just a little correction, your regex in that case should be `"(PNAM|SSTA|STAR)=([^|]*)\\|"`

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work for you?

```
String str = "STAR=20110209 00:01:01|PNAM=test_.xml|PNUM=480|SSTA=20110209 00:01:01|STRT=20110209 00:01:01|STOP=20110209 00:01:01";
String[] parts = str.split("\\|");

for (String part : parts)
{
    String[] nameValue = part.split("=");

    if (nameValue[0] == "somekey")
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: should be str.split("\\|"); or you'll get interesting results.

Comment: I dont want to go with split twice as their can be 100 key,value pairs and doing it this way seems over kill.

Comment: 100 pairs looks like small change, really.

Answer (score 2):

So, the way your problem is really isn't best solved with regular expressions. Instead, use split() like someone else has offered, but instead of having a crazy if loop, load everything into a map.

```
String str = "STAR=20110209 00:01:01|PNAM=test_.xml|PNUM=480|SSTA=20110209 00:01:01|STRT=20110209 00:01:01|STOP=20110209 00:01:01";
String[] parts = str.split("|");
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (String part : parts) {
    String[] nameValue = part.split("=");
    properties.put(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]);
}
```

Then all you have to do is, `properties.get("PNUM")`

Comment: Same as other split based answer. `|` needs to be escaped otherwise it will split on every character in original string (including start and end of text).